# ElasticSearch - calling UpdateByQuery and Update in parallel causes 409 conflicts

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Working with large index (100,000 documents), I have a use case that spawns several threads who are trying to update documents in parallel, the source code uses two methods in updating the documents: `Update` and `UpdateByQuery`, so some of the threads calls `Update` and some of them calls `UpdateByQuery`.
For the sake of brevity, each of the threads tries to update the same property for the entire documents.

Here is a small POC that demonstrate the use case:

Indexing 100,000 documents of `Product` type, and spawn 100 tasks so each task calls `Update` and `UpdateByQuery` in parallel. both of them uses `MatchAll` query.

```
public async Task ConflictsTestAsync()
{
    // index 100,000 documents.
    IEnumerable<Product> products = CreateProducts(100000);
    await _client.IndexManyAsync(products);

    await _client.Indices.UpdateSettingsAsync("MyIndex", s => s
        .IndexSettings(i => i.Setting(UpdatableIndexSettings.MaxResultWindow, 100000)));

    var searchResponse = _client.Search<Product>(s => s
        .From(0)
        .Size(100000)
        .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
    );
    IReadOnlyCollection<IHit<Product>> getProducts = searchResponse.Hits;

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(UpdateByQuery(getProducts));
        tasks.Add(Update(getProducts));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

public class Product
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

UpdateByQuery (update the price to be 0):

```
private async Task UpdateByQuery()
{
    Func<UpdateByQueryDescriptor<Product>, IUpdateByQueryRequest> updateByQuerySelector = (UpdateByQueryDescriptor<Product> updateByQueryDescriptor) =>
    {
        updateByQueryDescriptor
            .Conflicts(Conflicts.Abort)
            .ErrorTrace()
            .Query(x => x.MatchAll())
            .Script(x => x.Source("ctx._source['price'] = '0'"));               

        IUpdateByQueryRequest result = updateByQueryDescriptor;
        return result;
    };

    await _client.UpdateByQueryAsync(updateByQuerySelector, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Update (update the price to be 1):

```
private async Task Update(IReadOnlyCollection<IHit<Product>> keys)
{
    foreach (IHit<Product> product in keys)
    {
        DocumentPath<Product> id = new DocumentPath<Product>(product.Id);
        Func<UpdateDescriptor<Product, Product>, IUpdateRequest<Product, Product>> updateSelector = (UpdateDescriptor<Product, Product> updateDescriptor) =>
        {
            var page = product.Source;
            page.Price = "1";

            updateDescriptor.Doc(page);

            IUpdateRequest<Product, Product> result = updateDescriptor;

            return result;
        };

        await _client.UpdateAsync<Product>(id, updateSelector);
    }
}
```

The problem is spawning multiple threads of Query and UpdateByQuery causes conflicts exceptions:

Some of the `Update` throws:

> Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (409) low level call
> on POST: /MyIndex/_update/d75a34ae-2533-4e15-a852-13e98c5b599c
> Audit trail of this API call:
>
> - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.2495465
>   OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 409 from: POST
>   /MyIndex/_update/d75a34ae-2533-4e15-a852-13e98c5b599c.
>   ServerError: Type: version_conflict_engine_exception Reason:
>   "[d75a34ae-2533-4e15-a852-13e98c5b599c]: version conflict, required
>   seqNo [701069], primary term [1]. current document has seqNo [702042]
>   and primary term [1]"
>   Request: {"doc":{"id":"d75a34ae-2533-4e15-a852-13e98c5b599c","manufacturer":"777e1602-8390-40c8-817e-fdef4e3fb9c0","price":"1","title":"31184e90-f1d1-45be-8746-496a50de2f97","description":"780cc1ab-0a8b-4114-a840-67a528de8e55"}}
>   Response: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"version_conflict_engine_exception","reason":"[d75a34ae-2533-4e15-a852-13e98c5b599c]:
>   version conflict, required seqNo [701069], primary term [1]. current
>   document has seqNo [702042] and primary term
>   [1]","index_uuid":"gFAfYHfNQZG0tD0L2a9yag","shard":"0","index":"MyIndex"}],"type":"version_conflict_engine_exception","reason":"[d75a34ae-2533-4e15-a852-13e98c5b599c]:
>   version conflict, required seqNo [701069], primary term [1]. current
>   document has seqNo [702042] and primary term
>   [1]","index_uuid":"gFAfYHfNQZG0tD0L2a9yag","shard":"0","index":"MyIndex"},"status":409}

And some of the `UpdateByQuery` throws (I've cleaned the failures array):

> Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (409) low level call
> on POST:
> /MyIndex/_update_by_query?conflicts=abort&error_trace=true
> Audit trail of this API call:
>
> - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.2636546
>   OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 409 from: POST
>   /MyIndex/_update_by_query?conflicts=abort&error_trace=true
>   Request: {"query":{"match_all":{}},"script":{"source":"ctx._source['price'] =
>   '0'"}}
>   Response: {"took":120,"timed_out":false,"total":100000,"updated":0,"deleted":0,"batches":1,"version_conflicts":1000,"noops":0,"retries":{"bulk":0,"search":0},"throttled_millis":0,"requests_per_second":-1.0,"throttled_until_millis":0,"failures":[{"index":"MyIndex","type":"_doc","id":"d5fb4183-4ff4-43c9-962c-ee9d0ee59a6b","cause":{"type":"version_conflict_engine_exception","reason":"[d5fb4183-4ff4-43c9-962c-ee9d0ee59a6b]:
>   version conflict, required seqNo [0], primary term [1]. current
>   document has seqNo [100000] and primary term
>   [1]","index_uuid":"pPDFKhj6T4y-MpzYECKpxQ","shard":"0"]}

Because performance are important I prefer not to give up on `UpdateByQuery` (and uses only `Update`) or mutexing the methods access, any suggestion to deal with this situation will be appreciated.

Update:
Data integrity is important: `.Conflicts(Conflicts.Abort)`

ElasticSearch: 7.10.0.

Comment: use `seq_no` and `primary_term` for optimistic concurrency control: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/optimistic-concurrency-control.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:
You can pass `conflicts=proceed` to the `update_by_query` API if you want it to continue working even when hitting conflicts.

More details:
The [update_by_query page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) explains:

> When you submit an update by query request, Elasticsearch gets a
> snapshot of the data stream or index when it begins processing the
> request and updates matching documents using internal versioning. When
> the versions match, the document is updated and the version number is
> incremented. If a document changes between the time that the snapshot
> is taken and the update operation is processed, it results in a
> version conflict and the operation fails. You can opt to count version
> conflicts instead of halting and returning by setting conflicts to
> proceed.

So basically, your `update` and `update_by_query` are trying to update the same documents, conflicting with each other. Using `conflicts=proceed` makes that operation say "oh well, I'll just continue to update the other docs".

Comment: Hey Doron, thanks but I can't have some of the documents not updated, it will hurt my data integrity

Comment: So you need to make sure each call updates different documents

Comment: Btw 100k documents is not a lot. You should be fine with a single update by query call. You can add slices=auto to make it faster. ES will do the hard work of parallelizing the job for you